# PROLOG - Generate a list of all connected components of a graph

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I learnt prolog this month at school, I'm still an absolute newbie at it.

What I'm trying to achieve is generating all connected components in one list.

My idea is to run multiple DFS on the graph, each DFS once finished will generate a list let's say LC to be appended to a result list ALL_LC.

I found some code online, which is very helpful to start with.

---

```
connected(a,b).
connected(b,e).
connected(c,d).
isConnected(X,Y) :- connected(X,Y).
isConnected(X,Y) :- connected(Y,X).
next_node(Current, Next, Path) :-
    isConnected(Current, Next),
    not(member(Next, Path)).

dfs(Goal, Goal, _, [Goal]).
dfs(Start, Goal, Visited, [Start|Path]) :-
    next_node(Start, Next_node, Visited),
    dfs(Next_node, Goal, [Next_node|Visited], Path).
```

---

First of all I thought of editing my DFS function, since I don't know the GOAL (what node trying to reach), I only have a set of roots to start with in every step. Some I'll skip since they were visited.

Any ideas how can I get to edit DFS in order to get there?

Comment: What do you mean by a "list of all connected components"? Do you mean a list of nodes that aren't isolated? Or a list of all possible paths between two specified nodes? Or something else? The example code you found will succeed for paths between two nodes.

Comment: I wanna generate a List of lists of nodes that have pathes between them. Each group in a separate list.

Comment: What are "patches"? Do you mean paths? Could you give a simple example? What do you expect the result to look like for your small `connected/2` database?

Comment: @lurker let a graph G(V,E) where V=[a,b,c,d,e] and E=[[a,b],[b,c],[d,e]]. For this sample R would have two entries. R=[[a,b,c],[d,e]]. Two connected components.